# get commmon properties of two different object using c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to get *common properties* (i.e .properties having *same name*) from objects of two different classes into an *array*. But I'm not able to provide the correct syntax near `Join`. This is my code. Please, help

```
        PropertyInfo[] objAllProps = SourceInstance.GetType().GetProperties();
        PropertyInfo[] objAllProps_Target = TargetInstance.GetType().GetProperties();

        PropertyInfo[] CommonProperties = 
              from allprops in objAllProps join 
                   allprop_target in objAllProps_Target on 
                       allprops.Name.Equals(allprop_target)
            select new PropertyInfo[] {
                       allprop_target,
                   }
            .ToArray<PropertyInfo>();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest *different* collection's type `HashSet<string>` instead of `PropertyInfo[]`:

```
   HashSet<string> NamesToFind = new HashSet<string>(SourceInstance
     .GetType()
     .GetProperties()
     .Select(property => property.Name));

   // Common properties: properties of TargetInstance such that
   // there's a property of SourceInstance with the same name
   PropertyInfo[] CommonProperties = TargetInstance
     .GetType()
     .GetProperties()
     .Where(property => NamesToFind.Contains(property.Name))
     .ToArray();
```

Comment: tx dmitry..it did the job :-).